# Rewrite C# files before they get processed by the compiler in MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm looking for a way to extend the existing MSBuild compilation flow for C# projects, by rewriting certain code files before they get picked up by the compiler. More specifically, I want to process files with top-level statements, and wrap the underlying code within a custom class/method, instead of the auto-generated `<Program>$.Main()`.

In other words, given a C# project with the following two compilation units:

- `Foo.cs`

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Foo");
```

- `Bar.cs`

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Bar");
```

I want to inject some processing logic, so that these files are instead passed to the compiler as:

- `Foo.g.cs`

```cs
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

- `Bar.g.cs`

```cs
public static class Bar
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

At the same time, I want the user to maintain full static analysis, autocompletion, and other compiler-powered IDE features when editing the original `Foo.cs` and `Bar.cs` files. That means, if the generated file contains an error, I want it to be reported on the original file instead.

Ultimately, my goal is to enable the user to author top-level statements in multiple files, while having my framework call `Execute()` on the generated code to execute all of them (the order is not important).

**What's the best approach and the minimal set of steps I'd need to undertake in order to implement something like this?**

My original idea was to do the following:

1. Exclude the original files from compilation, but include them as `<None>` items so that they stay as part of the project
2. Generate the output files (using a source generator or just a simple MSBuild task)
3. Use `#line` directives to remap all static analysis from the generated files onto the original files

- `Project.csproj`

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="*.cs" />
    <None Include="*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- `Foo.g.cs`

```cs
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
#line 1 "File.cs"
Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

This works well with `dotnet build` (errors are reported on the original file), but has suboptimal behavior inside IDEs:

- In VS Code, this works fine, but OmniSharp continues saying that "Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements", despite the files not being part of the compilation at all. Using `#pragma warning disable CS8802` had no effect. The errors also took a while to repeat and would sometimes get "stuck" until I manually ran `dotnet build`.
- In Visual Studio and JetBrains Rider, line remapping appears to not be respected at all. No errors are shown in the original files and no static analysis is performed on them. Syntax highlighting works, though, including symbol detection (I can inspect method signatures, jump to definition, etc.).

Note: I tried to keep the description of the problem as simple as possible, but my main idea here is to prototype a new test framework that would use TLS to define tests (as opposed to classes and methods), similar to how it's done in other languages: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/Hallstatt

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this? This seems like bad practice, what is your motivation for putting a wrapper around literally everything?

Comment: @Kief my motivation is to allow top-level statements in more than just one compilation unit. For practical examples, see my framework's proof-of-concept [here](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/Hallstatt#basic-example) and language proposal to C# [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4163).

Comment: No idea off the top of my head, but maybe [C# Scripting APIs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples.md) could help here?

Comment: Feels like you're after a Source generator? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/

Comment: @bc3tech yes, I could use source generators to create the generated files, but the main challenge is providing static analysis on the original files, while excluding them from compilation. I want all errors in the generated files to be reported on the original files.

Comment: @Tyrrrz so, maybe some combination of a source generator and an analyzer?
The source generator generates a `.g.cs` file.
The analyzer then runs an in-memory compilation of the `.g.cs` files from the generator.
For all diagnostics it gets, it applies an offset to the location, depending on how the `.g.cs` files are created, and reports those on the `.cs` files.
The reference from `.g.cs` to `.cs` could be established by some attribute.
The difficulty would be respecting `.editorconfig` rules etc..
Also, I don't know if an analyzer can report on files that are not part of the compilation.

Comment: Are you interested in a solution where each top-level statement is in a separate assembly? I found a way to do this to avoid `CS8802`, but still be able to call all of the top-level statements from your framework. It takes contortions, but is possible without a source generator, analyzer, or pre-compile step. If so, I can make an answer.

Comment: @svenhuebner that could work in theory. I'd have to experiment with that.

Comment: @Kit as long as the original files are _authored_ inside a single assembly (project), I don't care how exactly they're processed in actuality. That means that the user should be able to create multiple TLS files as part of a single project.

Answer (score 12):

To maintain both

> ... full static analysis, autocompletion, and other compiler-powered IDE features when editing the original Foo.cs and Bar.cs files. That means, if the generated file contains an error, I want it to be reported on the original file instead.

and

> ... enabl[ing] the user to author top-level statements in multiple files, while having my framework call Execute() on the generated code to execute all of them...

is going to be difficult.

I've found one way to do it with ***serious limitations and caveats***. Other solutions such as source generators, custom pre-compilation scripts/build steps and dynamic code generation *might* be possible, but they would have their own baggage.

> **NOTE: I'm not advocating this.** My solution is likely *very* brittle, and it's *highly* abusing the idiomatic way of doing things in .NET. Ultimately, I'd have what you term the "user" (I'll refer to this without the quotes later) do the normal thing of authoring a method in a class in a namespace (in a file by itself for source control purposes). But that said, diving in...

**Limitation 1**

Each top-level statement would have to live in a separate `.csproj`. It's unfortunate, but the .NET world imposes a physical boundary (the project/the assembly) for code *prior* to imposing a logical boundary (a namespace). To avoid `CS8802` you have no choice but to put each top-level statement code in a separate project.

If we are OK with this limitation, the user experience prior to compilation [is a breeze](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+a+breeze). They get their top-level static analysis happiness, and, at debug time, they can run their "main" and get great debugger support and isolation from other users doing their work.

**Caveat 1**

But, it's weird. Each of these separate `.csproj` must be executables (likely console projects), and for you, the framework developer, how can you deal with all these projects?

Well, the usual thing is to add a project reference. You'd need to add one for every "top-level experience". You *can* add an executable project as a reference to a library or another executable (e.g. your framework) because .NET exe's and dll's are still assemblies.

It sort of inverts the build process. I understand not wanting to take hard references into the framework. A certain measure of runtime inspection would be required most likely, ala the days of [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/).

**Limitations 2 & 3**

Top-level statements have NO namespace or, more correctly, their namespace is the root namespace. That means each of these top-level statements will have the same namespace, class, and method: `global::Program.<Main>$` as seen decompiled:

[image]

Worse, the accessibility to the class and method is `internal`.

**Caveats 2 & 3**

So how do you get around `internal` and how do you get around identical types and signatures? The answer is to apply [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute) and alias the namespace for each reference.

In the consumed projects add the attribute to your top-level statement file (I know, it's not cool and sort of defeats the purpose, but there you go).

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ClassLibrary1")]

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

And in the consuming project, what I'm calling `ClassLibrary1`, add the `Aliases` element to each of the project references.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1.csproj">
    <Aliases>One</Aliases>
  </ProjectReference>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp6.csproj">
    <Aliases>Two</Aliases>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

To make this multi-project experience less onerous, you could create a template for your users, perhaps customizing it from the C# [Console Application Template](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/tree/main/template_feed/Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.8.0/content/ConsoleApplication-CSharp). In this template you could add a C# file, say `InternalsVisibleTo.cs` with these contents:

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ClassLibrary1")]
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) for how to create a custom template and how to install it. Once you do, your users can use `dotnet new nameOfTemplate` or Visual Studio to quickly add a project. The created `Program.cs` now won't have these boilerplate lines, and the user can just ignore `InternalsVisibleTo.cs`.

**Executing this Mess**

To call each of the user's top-level statements, you can use reflection and the `extern alias` directive:

```cs
using static System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

namespace ClassLibrary1;

extern alias Two;
extern alias One;

public static class Class1
{
    public static void YourExecutor()
    {
        var method = typeof(One::Program).GetMethod("<Main>$", NonPublic | Static);
        method?.Invoke(null, new object?[] { Array.Empty<string>() });
        method = typeof(Two::Program).GetMethod("<Main>$", NonPublic | Static);
        method?.Invoke(null, new object?[] { Array.Empty<string>() });
    }
}
```

Of course, you'd want a variation of that, which somehow finds all the user's statements via reflection. I just provided an example here.

The above was tested. Here's that simple test, which runs as expected.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class Tester
{
    [Test]
    public void ThisIsCrazy()
    {
        Class1.YourExecutor();
    }
}
```

**Final Caveats**

This is clearly abnormal from the usual (idiomatic) way of doing things when you're writing plugins, frameworks, and attempting to generalize code, but it works.

Yet,

- AOT compilation will likely defeat this whole approach.
- Non-public changes make this brittle (what happens if `<Main>$` is no longer correct)?
- There's a burden on your users to add a few lines and to understand *why* these are necessary.

As always, it comes down to the usual tradeoffs in programming.

**Coda** ([what is a coda?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coda))

Without a change to the .NET CLR to allow multiple top-level statements, via some sort of virtual dispatch (or other mechanism), even source generators would end up short.

They'll end up short because the experience would fail at the static analysis level *and* at the debugging level, which relies on the static level to some degree.

> I'd actually like to know if my assertion above is correct or not.

Your "ask" is not odd or crazy, but it defies current convention and implementation. Put simply, top-level statements were coded to purpose: the purpose being simplified execution of a **single** program without boilerplate.

An idiomatic change in the language (C#) and/or the runtime (.NET), will require some kind of tradeoff that's reasonable for you and your users (convenience/boilerplate/experience/testing) and... the larger community.

I think you'll have to find an acceptable balance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! Most of the limitations you listed shouldn't actually be a problem. The framework would expose its entry point via the test adapter interface, which would allow it to execute with `dotnet test` on all projects in the solution. Then, I'd be able to get each individual assembly's entry points and run them quite easily via reflection. That being said, forcing the user to create a separate project for each TLS file is a deal breaker, as the whole goal of this exercise is to reduce boilerplate (hence why I want to utilize TLS) :(

Comment: Yeah, I figured that the separate solutions would be a bit problematic. Perhaps `dotnet new` and any other automation could alleviate this. Boilerplate isn't necessarily bad if you can ignore it.

Comment: @Tyrrrz I added a way to alleviate some of the multi-project pain, but certainly not all of it.